# How to export Tally ledger opening and cloing balance Per Month

Tags: xml, tally

```
    <ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <IMPORTDATA>
      <REQUESTDESC>
        <REPORTNAME>Ledger</REPORTNAME>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
          <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>{company name}</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
          <SVBANKNAME>{bank name}</SVBANKNAME>
         
        </STATICVARIABLES>
      </REQUESTDESC>
      <REQUESTDATA>
      </REQUESTDATA>
    </IMPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

I use this syntax but its not working

my company have username and password so how to get ??

Comment: you need to open tally company by entering username and password.
if company is not opened it will not work

Comment: Its possible to postman ??

Comment: If you want data through xml , you need to keep the company open,
the app you are using to send xml doesnt matter